# Reassign CTL + Backspace on External Keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos

I have an external Apple Keyboard. I am used to using FN + DELETE to invoke Backspace on my laptop, but this keyboard does not have the Function Key in the same location.

There in an actual Backspace button on this keyboard, but my instinct now is to hit FN + Delete.

I've been looking at the Keyboard Shortcuts in the Settings Application, but it is not letting me set a Backspace combo, and/or it is not letting me set a CTRL + DELETE combo.

I have also looked at "Modifier Keys" in Keyboard Settings, but that does not provide access to the Function key.

Any ideas how I can set this up?

Running El Capitan.

Comment: Have you checked out the Karabiner app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) application is a good way to re-assign specific keyboard shortcuts like this, with a huge number of built-in customisations you can enable individually.

I believe the one you are asking for is supported, under the grouping "Change Delete Key", listed as "Control+Delete to Forward Delete".